# SET in LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: mysql, sql, file

OK, I thought I can figure it out by myself but I just don't seem to see it. The goal for me is to fill table MODELOS in following manner:

```
+--------+----------+---------+
| ID_MOD | ID_MARCA | MODELO  |
+--------+----------+---------+
|      1 |        1 | C2      |
|      2 |        1 | C3      |
|      3 |        1 | C4      |
|      4 |        1 | PICASSA |
|      5 |        2 | MONDEO  |
|      6 |        2 | S-MAX   |
|      7 |        3 | ACCORD  |
|      8 |        3 | CIVIC   |
|      9 |        4 | CLS     |
|     10 |        5 | 900     |
|     11 |        6 | IBIZA   |
|     12 |        6 | LEON    |
|     13 |        7 | 307     |
|     14 |        7 | 308     |
|     15 |        7 | 407     |
|     16 |        7 | 408     |
|     17 |        8 | MEGANE  |
|     18 |        9 | GOLF    |
|     19 |        9 | PASSAT  |
|     20 |        9 | TOUAREG |
+--------+----------+---------+
```

I've got this table:

```
mysql> select * from MARCAS;
+----------+------------+
| ID_MARCA | MARCA      |
+----------+------------+
|        1 | CITROEN    |
|        2 | FORD       |
|        3 | HONDA      |
|        4 | MERCEDES   |
|        7 | PEUGEOT    |
|        8 | RENAULT    |
|        5 | SAAB       |
|        6 | SEAT       |
|        9 | VOLKSWAGEN |
+----------+------------+
```

and following file to work with:

```
"MARCA"#"MODELO"#"MATRICULA"#PRECIO
"CITROEN"#"PICASSA"#"CPG-2044"#12000
"CITROEN"#"PICASSA"#"CPR-1762"#12500
"CITROEN"#"C4"#"FPP-1464"#13500
"CITROEN"#"C4"#"FDR-4563"#13000
"CITROEN"#"C3"#"BDF-8856"#8000
"CITROEN"#"C3"#"BPZ-7878"#7500
"CITROEN"#"C2"#"CDR-1515"#5000
"CITROEN"#"C2"#"BCC-3434"#4500
"FORD"#"MONDEO"#"BTG-3267"#8000
"FORD"#"MONDEO"#"BPP-6792"#8200
"FORD"#"S-MAX"#"FDR-1564"#20000
"FORD"#"S-MAX"#"FCE-9327"#21000
"HONDA"#"CIVIC"#"FCC-7764"#16000
"HONDA"#"CIVIC"#"FBC-4567"#14000
"HONDA"#"ACCORD"#"FFC-6768"#22000
"HONDA"#"ACCORD"#"FPB-2231"#23000
"MERCEDES"#"CLS"#"FDR-2265"#31000
"SAAB"#"900"#"FPG-1165"#21000
"SEAT"#"LEON"#"DVB-1119"#14500
"SEAT"#"LEON"#"DCR-5634"#13500
"SEAT"#"IBIZA"#"DPR-3434"#9500
"SEAT"#"IBIZA"#"DPP-8756"#10000
"PEUGEOT"#"307"#"DGX-4598"#5500
```

etc.

Now, what I've achieved is:

```
mysql> select * from MODELOS;
+--------+----------+---------+
| ID_MOD | ID_MARCA | MODELO  |
+--------+----------+---------+
|      1 |     NULL | MODELO  |
|      2 |     NULL | PICASSA |
|      3 |     NULL | C4      |
|      4 |     NULL | C3      |
|      5 |     NULL | C2      |
|      6 |     NULL | MONDEO  |
|      7 |     NULL | S-MAX   |
|      8 |     NULL | CIVIC   |
|      9 |     NULL | ACCORD  |
|     10 |     NULL | CLS     |
|     11 |     NULL | 900     |
|     12 |     NULL | LEON    |
|     13 |     NULL | IBIZA   |
|     14 |     NULL | 307     |
|     15 |     NULL | 308     |
|     16 |     NULL | 407     |
|     17 |     NULL | 408     |
|     18 |     NULL | MEGANE  |
|     19 |     NULL | PASSAT  |
|     20 |     NULL | GOLF    |
|     21 |     NULL | TOUAREG |
+--------+----------+---------+
```

Using, these commands:

```
ALTER TABLE MODELOS ADD UNIQUE(MODELO);
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE myfile.txt
IGNORE INTO TABLE MODELOS
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '#' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES ENDED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(@ignore1, MODELO, @ignore2, @ignore3);
```

How can I get that to create desired output? I suspect that the easiest way to do it will be by using SET sentence in LOAD DATA INFILE, but I just don't know how?

Comment: I suggest doing it in two steps. First load into `MODELOS` as you've written, then use `UPDATE MODELOS JOIN MARCAS` to merge in the `ID_MARCA` fields.

Comment: I did think of it. But not sure if 2 step approach is going to fly with my tutor. However it's def worth considering if anything else fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a query in the `SET` clause.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE myfile.txt
IGNORE INTO TABLE MODELOS
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '#' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES ENDED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(@marca, modelo, @ignore2, @ignore3)
SET ID_MARCA = (SELECT ID_MARCA FROM MARCAS WHERE MARCA = @marca)
```

This uses the first column in the file to look up the corresponding ID in the `MARCAS` table.

Comment: That gives me exactly the same result as before. Could you elaborate a bit on how that SET sentence works? Maybe there's simple change that I can make and would make the whole difference? Thanks for your input. It's appreaciated.

Comment: I misread the file, I didn't understand the relationship between the file and the `MARCAS` table. Try the new one that uses the user variable `@marca` for the first column of the file.

Comment: I did try that before (along with few other combinations) and it does not load any data into ID_MARCA column (I need to figure it out why). I've gave up on it (for now anyway) and just going to do it through temporary table. Thanks again for your input.